# Quill 'text-changed' event firing on data load

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, quill, textchanged

I am looking to add functionality to my Quill rich Text boxes where if the user makes a change to Rich Text box then they are prompted to either remain or discard changes if they try to navigate away from the page. I am creating my text-change event as follows:

```
quill.on('text-change', function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
    quillChanged = true;
});
```

Which is fine. If there is a change to the text then the event is fired, my variable is changed and I handle things from there. However, the Event Trigger is also fired when the rich Text boxes are auto-populated on Page Load.. Which I don't want.

I have seen a WPF example with a similar (non Quill) issue, and the answer there was to use a `this.IsLoaded` check. I'm wondering if there is something similar here for quill or if there are any other more practical ideas? I have thought about creating hidden fields to store the original page-load values for each text box but that is all starting to feel a bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the way the fields were being populated - not the trigger itself.

The code to populate the editors was:

```
$j('.ql-editor', container)[0].innerHTML = htmlInputString;
```

This was triggering the event. I simply changed this to be

```
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(htmlInputString, 'api');
```

And now the HTMl gets applied as expected and the trigger is not fired when the field is populated.

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a good way to do.. Maybe check the `source` instead to detect when it originates from `api` or `user`?

Comment: I had done that and all calls to the event come from 'user'. In this way you are not only able to pass the source value itself, it also doesn't raise the Event Trigger.

Comment: Is there something more 'Dangerous' to the 'dangerouslyPasteHTML' than I see?